# When I try to add a new node to MAAS, does the node need a physical internet connection?

Tags: networking, maas

I have two networks:

1. For local and internet connection
2. For MAAS Network as a private network

Here are my questions:

1. When I try to add a new node to MAAS, does the node need a physical internet connection?... because it tries to download something from the internet (Ubuntu) site?
2. Why does it need something from the internet, because I thought everything is ready to use in MAAS and nodes can get those from the MAAS Server?
3. If it needs an internet connection, how we can connect the server to the internet? Because as you know when we try to add a node we have to define its main network that private network which is not connected to the internet!! So I get a cannot connect to the internet error at the last step of node enlisting!

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes it needs Access to the Internet. It connectes to the ubuntu archives to download packages that are needed to perform a few tasks.

2) MAAS has a squid-deb-proxy server. This means that nodes will try to access the squid-deb-proxy to download whatever packages it needs. However, you might be experiencing an issue where it is not trying to do that, instead, is trying to access the internet directly. What version of MAAS are you using?

3) MAAS should probably be the default gateway and it should be configured to do NAT.

Comment: My MAAS version is 1.5 .                                            and I set other network adaptor ( connected to internet as Default GW. because I need to get SSH connection from MAAS server from other client outside of the Server Room!

Comment: How Can I set the MAAS Network adaptor to do nat on ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Do I need to config NAT on router? Do I need any specific router for NAT?